# Algebraic equation with 4 components

Tags: algebra

I need help solving:

$x^{3}-x^{2}-3x-1=0$

I understand using a calculator to find the zeros is fairly easy, but I would like to learn how to solve this equation by hand.

Thank you

Comment: You need to code this formulas and algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to the software *Mathematica*, however I reckon it would be found too trivial to be on *math.SE*

Comment: I'm voting this question because you can code the calculus recipe with Mathematica, printing what the case is, and plotting the function in range of the roots and vertex

Comment: Always try 0, -1, 1,-2, 2 . At least while undergradaute ...